# $ 1+(1/\sqrt{3})-(a/\sqrt{2})+(1/\sqrt{5})+(1/\sqrt{7})-(a/\sqrt{4})+(1/\sqrt{9})+(1/\sqrt{11})-(a/\sqrt{6})... $ Converges By comparison test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

For what value of real constant $a$ does the following series converge?
$$
1+(1/\sqrt{3})-(a/\sqrt{2})+(1/\sqrt{5})+(1/\sqrt{7})-(a/\sqrt{4})+(1/\sqrt{9})+(1/\sqrt{11})-(a/\sqrt{6})...
$$
I do not have a clue on how to proceed. Suggest a possible route.

can we do it by comparison test somehow? Can we comapre it with   $c/\sqrt{(n)}$ for some $c$ and some large enough $n$?

Comment: It is not clear what the terms of the series are supposed to be.

Comment: what is not clear?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think I can guess at the pattern with the most recent addition
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{\sqrt{4n+1}}+\frac1{\sqrt{4n+3}}-\frac{a}{\sqrt{2n+2}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{(4n+3)(2n+2)}+\sqrt{(4n+1)(2n+2)}-a\sqrt{(4n+1)(4n+3)}}{\sqrt{(4n+1)(4n+3)(2n+2)}}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{(1+\frac3{4n})(1+\frac1n)}+\sqrt{(1+\frac1{4n})(1+\frac1n)}-a\sqrt2\sqrt{(1+\frac1{4n})(1+\frac3{4n})}}{2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{(1+\frac1{4n})(1+\frac3{4n})(1+\frac1n)}}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left[1+O(\frac1n)\right]+\left[1+O(\frac1n)\right]-a\sqrt2\left[1+O(\frac1n)\right]}{2\sqrt{n}\left[1+O(\frac1n)\right]}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2-a\sqrt2+O(\frac1n)}{2\sqrt{n}}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
where $O(\cdot)$ is Landau [big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). Since convergence concerns the tail of the sequence, we can replace the term for $n=0$ by it value, $1+\frac1{\sqrt3}-\frac{a}{\sqrt2}$, and start using $O(\frac1n)$ for $n\ge1$.

The sum in $(1)$ will converge if and only if $a=\sqrt2$.

Comment: What are you denoting with $O(\frac1n)$. This may be obvious but I am a non Maths student taking Maths course for the first time.

Comment: $O(\frac1n)$ represents a function for which there is a constant, $c$, so that the absolute value of the function is no greater than $c/n$.

Comment: can we do it by comparison test somehow? Can we comapre it with   $c/\sqrt{(n)}$ for some $c$ and some large enough $n$?

Comment: @Martin: Since $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{O(\frac1n)}{2\sqrt{n}}$ converges by comparison to $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{n^3}}$, $(1)$ converges if and only if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2-a\sqrt2}{2\sqrt{n}}$ converges, and this only converges when $2-a\sqrt2=0$ by comparison to $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$.

Answer (score 1):

So, the terms come in blocks of three, where the sum of the $k$-th block of terms is
$$
s_k=y_{3k-2}+y_{3k-1}+y_{3k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4k-3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4k-1}}-\frac{a}{\sqrt{2k}}.
$$
Since the individual $y_i\rightarrow 0$, the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} y_k$ converges if and only if the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} s_k$ converges.  I suggest you calculate the asymptotic behavior of $s_k$.  For large $k$, $$s_k \sim A(a) k^{-1/2} + B(a) k^{-3/2}+O(k^{-5/2}),$$ so the sum converges if and only if $A(a)=0$.  Can you find what this implies about $a$?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on mjqxxxx's answer:

$s_k=y_{3k-2}+y_{3k-1}+y_{3k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4k-3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4k-1}}-\frac{a}{\sqrt{2k}}.$

By the binomial theorem,

$\begin{array}\\
(4k-c)^{-1/2}
&=(4k)^{-1/2}(1-\frac{c}{4k})^{-1/2}\\
&=(4k)^{-1/2}(1-\frac{c}{4k}\binom{-1/2}{1}+O(k^{-2}))\\
&=(4k)^{-1/2}(1+\frac{c}{8k}+O(k^{-2}))\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
(4k-1)^{-1/2}+(4k-3)^{-1/2}
&=(4k)^{-1/2}(2+\frac{4}{8k}+O(k^{-2}))\\
&=k^{-1/2}+\frac{1}{4k^{3/2}}+O(k^{-2}))\\
\end{array}
$

To get the
$k^{-1/2}$
term to get cancelled,
we must have
$\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}
=1
$
or
$a = \sqrt{2}$.